# Creating remote powershell session, no domain, no administrator password

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of learning powershell (no admin background either, I've just stumbled across it whilst studying Python and thought it was interesting), and I'm completely stuck on remoting.

I'm trying to remote from my Desktop computer("DAVE-PC") to my laptop("DAVE").

- They have a connection (Test-Connection cmdlet)
- Toth computers have "DAVE" AND "DAVE-PC" in their trusted hosts lists.
- Remoting enabled on both computers

:

```
PS C:\> get-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value                                                                                                                                                                                       
----            ----                           -------------   -----                                                                                                                                                                                       
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   DAVE-PC, DAVE                                                                                                                                                                               



PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DAVE -Credential Administrator
```

At this point, I'm prompted for a password, which I do not know:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server DAVE failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DAVE -Credential administrator
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DAVE:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

What are my options now to get remoting up and running?

Google seems to suggest I run a few scripts to change the password?

I've attempted to follow methods suggested in this link with no luck:
[Cannot create remote powershell session after Enable-PSRemoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062033/cannot-create-remote-powershell-session-after-enable-psremoting). I'm really not confident I know what I'm doing though as you might expect.

Comment: When you create a powershell session on a remote machine, you will have to provide credentials for the account on the remote machine. The session will then start in that account's context. Therefore you will have to enter the credentials for the administrator user of your laptop. If your laptop's administrator account doesn't have a password, set one. Also check if the administrator account is enabled on your laptop.

Comment: Thanks. Permissions for administrators on my laptop are set to 'full control' and I'm under administrator in both. I've checked the password age for both and they are years and years old, so I've never touched them. A bit more digging and I'll post back.

Comment: You don't have to use the `administrator` account, just use any account that is in the `administrators` group on the remote machine. Surely you must know a password for one administrator on your computers.

Comment: At this point I don't even know how to find out what accounts may be in the administrators group. When I have time later I'll get on it though.

Comment: Did you try this: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DAVE -Credential DAVE\Administrator` ?

Comment: I'm prompted for a password, which I do not know.

Comment: My Laptop, running Windows 8, does not have a 'Local Users and Groups' directory. So I had to resort to rooting around in my Desktop. After finding who was a member of what, I was finally able to remote from my laptop to my Desktop. So I've accomplished the task of remoting, just in the opposite direction to that which I wanted. I'll take it! Thanks for the input.